# Prove EM Waves Are Transverse In Nature

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, waves

Why we say that EM waves are transverse in nature? I have seen some proofs regarding my question but they all calculate flux through imaginary cube. Here is My REAL problem that I can't here imagine infinitesimal area for calculating flux because em line of force will intersect (perpendicular or not) surface at only one point so $E.ds$ will be zero so even flux through one surface of cube will always be zero. I am Bit Confused. I DON'T KNOW VECTOR CALCULUS BUT KNOW CALCULUS.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138770/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why we say that em waves are transverse in nature?

In a region empty of electric charge, we have, from Maxwell's equations:

$$\nabla \cdot \vec E = \nabla \cdot \vec B = 0$$

Since you don't yet know vector calculus, let's rewrite these divergence equations as so:

$$\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial E_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = 0 $$

$$\frac{\partial B_x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial B_y}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z} = 0 $$

Now, assume an electromagnetic wave is propagating in the $z$ direction so that the space and time variation of the field components are of the form

$$\cos(kz - \omega t)$$

Since the spatial variation is zero in the $x$ and $y$ directions, our equations become

$$\frac{\partial E_z}{\partial z} = 0$$

$$\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial z} = 0$$

Which means that electric and magnetic field components in the $z$ direction, the direction of propagation, *must be constant with respect to $z$*.

In other words, *only the electric and magnetic field components transverse to the direction of propagation vary with respect to $z$*. i.e., the electromagnetic wave is transverse.

---

Addendum to address a comment:

> Why spatial Variations are zero in both x and y directions.

We stipulated that the field components are of the form $\cos(kz - \omega t)$ which means the wave is propagating in the $z$ direction.

Clearly, the partial derivative of $\cos(kz - \omega t)$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ is zero.

Comment: @VishvajeetPatil, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I deleted my above comment because I understand before you said it to me.Sorry For late Response.Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You say the

> em line of force will intersect (if perpendicular) surface at only one point.

This is not the case for a plane wave, which is the simplest case one usually considers. I think I know what's going on to make you think this. This may or may not be the issue that helps you.

Take this typical picture of an EM wave.

[image]

It is so very tempting, yet incorrect, to think that the E and B field are only defined (non-zero) on that axis. No. Here's a better picture that only shows one of the two fields.

[image]

It's called a plane wave because the E and B fields have the same value everywhere on some plane. So if you imagine this wave incident on some cube, the dot product $\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S}$ has a value at more than just one point.

Comment: Why can't the first picture be right? Why, as you say the plane wave is simplest?

Comment: The first picture is right. It just hides a lot of the information. You should interpret the first picture as actually representing the second.

Comment: But why plane em wave is simplest?Please clarify in detail.Does what you are saying may somewhere related to particle nature in depth

Comment: That sounds like a different question. There should be plenty of internet material on it. If you can't find it, try asking as another question.

Comment: I NEED ANSWER PLEASE IF YOU KNOW IT THEN TELL ME HERE.

Comment: Plane waves are the simplest because all other waves can be written as sums of plane waves. BMS already answered your question. Try to be courteous.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to try to "unconfuse" you.

Let's start with a picture of ocean waves; as seen from the side, they look like "sine" waves (just like BMS's red EM wave); as seen from the top, the crests and troughs make **lines** (not points). The same thing happens with the E and B waves (make lines), and since they are perpendicular to each other, they form a **plane** (two lines make a plane). This is why the flux is evaluated over a **surface area** (**not** a point).

Comment: Would you infer that the flux of sound in a fluid must be evaluated along 1-dimensional path of sound propagation (think of velocity)? Or over a point (think of pressure), indeed?

Answer (score 0):

An EM wave is generated by the oscillation of an electron. Near the electron we have the near field and here all the wave components are non-zero. Far away from the source we have the far field and it is in the form of a spherical surface wave advancing along the radius of a sphere with centre at the source. If we take a small section of this spherical advancing surface we have a plane wave. Due to symmetry all components normal to the propagation direction cancel each other and become zero. This leaves a wave with variations of the z propagating wave component only varying with time and distance along z- hence the equation given in the other answers. Note that this applies to all waves from a single point.