# Why magnetic and electric field obey Helmholtz equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I am trying to understand the basic principles of scalar diffraction theory and came across the sentence "E and H obey the Helmholtz equation", what does that mean? Does that mean that each component of E and H field obey the same equation?

Comment: Since you mention wanting to understand scalar diffraction theory, my question received some good answer (although not 100% satisfying), have a look: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/311102/scalar-wave-approximation-to-electrodynamic-wave-equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. First, $E$ and $H$ (each separately) obey the same wave equation which says nothing else that the $E$ wave travels with the speed of light and has the same wavelength as the $H$ wave which, too, travels with the speed of light. The Helmholtz equation is obtained from the wave equation when one separates space and time variables to find particular solutions.

[Maxwell Vacuum Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Vacuum_equations,_electromagnetic_waves_and_speed_of_light)

[Helmholtz Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation)

Comment: With E you probably mean each component of E vector field obeys the Helmholtz equation. But dont forget that there is also a constraint on the solution which is div E=0.